# Server returned: EXPECTED_CRLF error when using pybeanstalk

Tags: python, python-2.7, beanstalkd

I am using pybeanstalk. When I try and produce a message to the tube, I get this error:

```
beanstalk.errors.ExpectedCrlf: Server returned: EXPECTED_CRLF
```

Here is the code I am executing:

```
message = str(message) + '\r\n'
data = job.Job(data=message, conn=self.beanstalk_connection)
data.Queue()
```

What is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: what the contents of `message`?  can you print `repr(message)` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Before I add the newline: `'516465'`. After I add the newline: `'516465\r\n'`

Comment: https://github.com/beanstalkd/pybeanstalk/issues/1. Maybe try to upgrade your package? or version of python? (not sure at all!)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yea, I had found that page too. I'm on Python 2.7.8 and pybeanstalk 1.0rc1. It'd be unrealistic for me to upgrade to python 3 at this time :-/ Thanks though!